# Sort the data on the basis of city list faster

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my VBA code which basically sorts the data on the basis of city list, while running the code it is taking time to complete, help me in finding a way to run this code faster.

```
Sub CopyDataByCity()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim citiesToFilter() As Variant
    Dim city As Variant
    Dim headerRow As Range
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim cityRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Set the source sheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Portfolio Summary")

    ' Set the target sheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW DATA")
    
    ' Set the range of cells containing the list of cities to filter on
    Set cityRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("City List").Range("A1:A271")

    ' Load the city names into an array
    ReDim citiesToFilter(1 To cityRange.Cells.Count)
    For Each cell In cityRange
        citiesToFilter(cell.Row - cityRange.Row + 1) = cell.Value
    Next cell
    
    ' Find the last row of data in the source sheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Get the header row
    Set headerRow = sourceSheet.Range("6:6")

    ' Set the starting row in the target sheet
    currentRow = 2 ' Assuming the header row is in row 1

    ' Loop through the cities to filter on in the desired order
    For Each city In citiesToFilter
        ' Loop through the rows in the source sheet
        For i = 8 To lastRow ' Assuming the header row is in row 7
            ' Check if the city name in column Q matches the current city
            If sourceSheet.Cells(i, "Q").Value = city Then
                ' If the city name matches, copy the specified columns and paste into the target sheet
                targetSheet.Range("A" & currentRow).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "C").Value ' Copy column
                targetSheet.Range("B" & currentRow).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "H").Value ' Copy column
                targetSheet.Range("C" & currentRow).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value ' Copy column
                targetSheet.Range("D" & currentRow).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "S").Value ' Copy column
                targetSheet.Range("E" & currentRow).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "I").Value ' Copy column
                targetSheet.Range("F" & currentRow).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "R").Value ' Copy column
                targetSheet.Range("G" & currentRow).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "W").Value ' Copy column
                targetSheet.Range("H" & currentRow).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "N").Value ' Copy column
                targetSheet.Cells(currentRow, "I").Value = city ' Paste the city name to column I in the target sheet
                currentRow = currentRow + 1 ' Increment the current row variable
            End If
            
            ' Check if the next row is blank or if the city changes
            If sourceSheet.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = "" Or sourceSheet.Cells(i + 1, "Q").Value <> city Then
                ' If the next row is blank or if the city changes, skip over it
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next city
End Sub
```

Comment: You could achieve that with a formula as well - if you have Excel 365: https://exceljet.net/formulas/sort-by-custom-list

Comment: any way in a code ?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code so it doesn't iterate through all the rows per city.
The main issue with your speed is that you check per city, each row and therein 11 times check a cell value and write 9 times (to targetSheet).

```
Sub CopyDataByCity()
    Const cityRows = 271
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, rCount As Long
    Dim citiesToFilter() As Variant
    Dim cityRng As Range
    Dim headerRow As Range
    Dim arrCity(), arrSum(), arrData(), cityValues()
    Dim colQ As String
    
    ' Set the source sheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Portfolio Summary")

    ' Set the target sheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW DATA")
    
    'Fill your array of cities
    ReDim arrCity(1 To cityRows)
    Set cityRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("City List").Range("A1:A" & cityRows)
    cityValues = cityRng.Value 'if this is not supposed to be hardcoded since your list may grow, use another lRow variable
    For i = 1 To UBound(cityValues, 1)
        arrCity(i) = UCase(CStr(cityValues(i, 1))) 'to get a 1D-array and make sure cities without a starting capital letter also get included
    Next i
    
    ' Find the last row of data in the source sheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Fill array of your sourceSheet to the last column you specified
    arrSum = sourceSheet.Range("A8:W" & lastRow).Value
    ReDim arrData(1 To UBound(arrSum, 1), 1 To 9) 'max rows for RAW DATA
    
    ' Get the header row
    Set headerRow = sourceSheet.Range("6:6") '<---- you assume the headerrow to be 7 later on?

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSum, 1)
        colQ = arrSum(i, 17)
        If IsInArray(UCase(colQ), arrCity) Then
            rCount = rCount + 1
            arrData(rCount, 1) = arrSum(i, 3) 'C-column
            arrData(rCount, 2) = arrSum(i, 8) 'H-column
            arrData(rCount, 3) = arrSum(i, 4) 'D-column
            arrData(rCount, 4) = arrSum(i, 19) 'S-column
            arrData(rCount, 5) = arrSum(i, 9) 'I-column
            arrData(rCount, 6) = arrSum(i, 18) 'R-column
            arrData(rCount, 7) = arrSum(i, 23) 'W-column
            arrData(rCount, 8) = arrSum(i, 14) 'N-column
            arrData(rCount, 9) = colQ
        End If
    Next i
    
    targetSheet.Range("A" & targetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1).Resize(rCount, 9).Value = arrData 'writes the data in the targetSheet
    lRow = targetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.AddCustomList cityRng
    targetSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    targetSheet.Range("A1:I" & lRow).Sort Key1:=targetSheet.Range("I1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    targetSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ' clean up
    Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

The function is to check whether the city is part of your list.
The order is something that was unclear to me if you needed it to be sorted as it is in "City List" or if you meant that "RAW DATA" was your sheet you wanted to sort further in.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: yes so basically i need the data in my raw data sheet in a sorted manner as per the city list

Comment: Edited in a custom sorting (based on your list), can you check if it works? First time using a custom sort so might have made a mistake ^^

Comment: this code works well, thanks man for the help, but is there any way to let me code know to paste only data for those cities which is in city list tab

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the code already checks if it's part of the list with `IsInArray`

Comment: so basically my code is also pasting the data which is not available on the list